# NSRange with location on iOS13 Not Working

Tags: swift, ios13, nsrange

My code not working with NSRange location on iOS13, on iOS12 and below it's work. Is there a way to color the text from the letters to be colored until the total letters afterwards? because I only have data starting from the colored letters and the total letters afterwards.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let text = "Testing Attributed Strings"
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        let dataStartIHave = 0
        let dataTotalIHave = 7

        attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location: dataStartIHave, length: dataTotalIHave))

        attributedLabel.attributedText = attributedString
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it's working, my code wrong because I include attributedLabel.text = text, after apply attributedText, so the text color will black all. So the wrong not NSRange with location.

Comment: @LorenRamly so just delete your post

Answer (score 3):

To get the range from the end of the word until the end of the text reliably you have to convert `NSRange` to `Range<String.Index>` and back

```
let text = "Testing Attributed Strings"
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
let dataStartIHave = 0
let dataTotalIHave = 7
let wordRange = NSRange(location: dataStartIHave, length: dataTotalIHave)
let upperBound = Range(wordRange, in: text)!.upperBound
let upperRange = NSRange(upperBound..., in: text)

attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: upperRange)
attributedLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

In Swift it's more efficient to get the `Range<String.Index>` from the word

```
let text = "Testing Attributed Strings"
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
if let testingRange = text.range(of: "Testing") {
    let upperRange = NSRange(testingRange.upperBound..., in: text)       
    attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: upperRange)
}
attributedLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: Yes it's working, my code wrong because I include attributedLabel.text = text, after apply attributedText, so the text color will black all. So the wrong not NSRange with location.

Comment: Nevertheless in Swift **never** create `NSRange` objects with integer location and length to apply it directly to the `range` parameter of `NSAttributedString` (or `NSRegularExpression`).

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

```
    attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location: dataStartIHave, length: dataTotalIHave))
```

Comment: Yes it's working, my code wrong because I include attributedLabel.text = text, after apply attributedText, so the text color will black all. So the wrong not NSRange with location.